# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.vfs.protocol.VirtualFileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

```
URL jarURL = ExternalOrdersManagerUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/session/utils/ExternalOrdersManagerUtils.class");
        JarURLConnection jurlConn = null;
        try {
            jurlConn = (JarURLConnection)jarURL.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        Manifest mf = null;
        try {
            mf = jurlConn.getManifest();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        Attributes attr = mf.getMainAttributes();
```

I used the Java 8 version and jboss-6.1.0.Final_cp version deployment server.
I got an error as follows. Please help me to fix this problem.

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.vfs.protocol.VirtualFileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnectionad.run(Thread.java:748) [:1.8.0_261]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the manifest using

```
new Manifest(ExternalOrdersManagerUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/manifest.mf"));
```